# How Can I move the caret/focus on a selected row and edit it?

Tags: winforms

I have a DataGridView that I load in unbound mode.
When first loaded the edit is set to 
I have a button where a user can "Add New"

Pressing this it will add a new row then
I do

```
dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;"
dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

However the caret focus is elsewhere.

I also would like the first cell to get the focus.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a BindingSource for your grid (lots of reasons)
   dgv.DataSource = bindingSourceCustomers;
2. bindingSourceCustomers.DataSource is unassigned (unbound)
3. Use bindingSourceCustomers.AddNew();
   Does exactly what you want.

More info here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.addnew.aspx